# Why req.query.code return a empty string?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, url

i'm trying to get the code from the url body with "req.query.code", but is empty and the url show perfectly the code, i don't know what happen, this is my server.js file:

```
app.get('/validate', async (req, res, next) => {
                if (!req.query.code || req.query.code != "") {
                    console.log(clc.red(`Error: No code provided`));
                    res.send(`Error: The code is missing, please check the documentation`);
                    return;
                }
                else {
                    console.log(req.query.code);
                }
}
```

And when i saw the error, the url have the code.

```
http://xxxxxxxx:3001/validate?code=xxxxxxxxxxa64779xxxxxe42fe16xx8063xxxx2xxxx
```

Comment: Read your code out loud "If code is not truthy or code is not an empty string."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have problem in your if condition in or operator in second condition you're checking for non-empty req.query.code because of which the if block is getting executed try this

```
            if (!req.query.code || req.query.code === "")
```

Comment: Bro, 1 hour searching the issue hahaha, thank you.